# Internal Server Error

Tags: linux, apache, fedora

The error message I gen when I try to access the web page server "192.168.50.29/cgi-bin/tinyPL.cgi"; looks like this:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.2.11 (Fedora) Server at 192.168.50.29 Port 80
```

Error_log :

```
 [Sat Oct 24 21:30:47 2009] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
 [Sat Oct 24 21:30:47 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
 [Sat Oct 24 21:30:47 2009] [notice] Digest: done
 [Sat Oct 24 21:30:48 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.9 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8g mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
 [Sat Oct 24 21:30:50 2009] [error] [client 192.168.50.69] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/tinyPL.cgi' failed
 [Sat Oct 24 21:30:50 2009] [error] [client 192.168.50.69] Premature end of script headers: tinyPL.cgi
```

Could any one help me on this!

Comment: Anything from the server error log?

Comment: What do you want to help with?

Comment: This seems to belong more on ServerFault, doesn't it?

Comment: Yea, more related to SF.

Comment: If he's trying to write a CGI program, then it belongs here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log file will have more details regarding the error, but an Internal Server error on a CGI script usually means that when the server tried to execute your CGI program the expected headers was not present.

In a perl script, that would be (for example):

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
print header();
```

Which will print out something like:

```
Content-type: text/html
```

Try and run your CGI script from the commandline and see if prints out those lines. The other problem might be due to access permissions. Apache might not be able to execute your script.